# (ES6) Filter data with an input field (min.array)

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, minimum

I'm working on a website where you can search for music. I want to put a filter option where people can filter on minimum age.

This is my JSON file:

```
{
  "artists":[
{
"name": "Martin Garrix",
"origin": "Netherlands",
"age": "22 years old",
"artist_id": "c0dc129d8a886a2c9bf487b826c3614a6630fb9c",
"best_song":"https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/98081145&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true"

},

{
  "name": "Armin van Buuren",
  "origin": "Netherlands",
  "age": "41 years old",
  "artist_id": "8b0a178ce06055312456cccc0c9aa7679d8054f1",
  "best_song":"https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/181749728&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true"
},

{
  "name": "Don Diablo",
  "origin": "Netherlands",
  "age": "38 years old",
  "artist_id": "178c6e7e3bf24710d4895048586a86f1bb81d842",
  "best_song":"https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/212802517&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true"


},

{
  "name": "David Guetta",
  "origin": "France",
  "age": "50 years old",
  "artist_id": "c2714423228a8012ad37af0186447cbb7ff589f7",
  "best_song":"https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/140006470&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true"


},

{
  "name": "Alesso",
  "origin": "Sweden",
  "age": "26 years old",
  "artist_id": "69fa09f6e181093fe0ea2ce1a4099066509f7837",
  "best_song":"https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/288914798&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true"

}
]
}
```

And this is my HTML:

```
<div class = "div-age">
<label for="age-select">Minimum age</label>
<input type="text" class = "search-age">
</div>
```

So for example; If you put 40 in the input field, you only get "Armin van Buuren" and "David Guetta".

This is what I have right now.

```
document.querySelector(`.search-age`).addEventListener(`keyup` , e => {
    const term = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
    const ageList = document.getElementsByClassName(`artist-info`);
    Array.from(ageList).forEach(function(ageList) {
      const artistAge = ageList.querySelector(`.age`).textContent;
      if (artistAge.toLowerCase().includes(term)) {
        ageList.style.display = `flex`;
      } else {
        ageList.style.display = `none`;
      }
    })
  });
```

The problem I have now, is that it only filter the exact number. So for example, I put 22, I only get "Martin Garrix"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to convert the age string to corresponding number using `parseInt` and then compare it to the value:

```
// Convert term and artist's age to corresponding integers
term = parseInt(term, 10);
artistAge = parseInt(artistAge, 10);

if (artistAge >= term) {
  ageList.style.display = `flex`;
} else {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

with [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), you can do the following way:

```js
const input = {
  artists: [
    {
      name: 'Martin Garrix',
      origin: 'Netherlands',
      age: '22 years old',
      artist_id: 'c0dc129d8a886a2c9bf487b826c3614a6630fb9c',
      best_song:
        'https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/98081145&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true',
    },

    {
      name: 'Armin van Buuren',
      origin: 'Netherlands',
      age: '41 years old',
      artist_id: '8b0a178ce06055312456cccc0c9aa7679d8054f1',
      best_song:
        'https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/181749728&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true',
    },

    {
      name: 'Don Diablo',
      origin: 'Netherlands',
      age: '38 years old',
      artist_id: '178c6e7e3bf24710d4895048586a86f1bb81d842',
      best_song:
        'https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/212802517&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true',
    },

    {
      name: 'David Guetta',
      origin: 'France',
      age: '50 years old',
      artist_id: 'c2714423228a8012ad37af0186447cbb7ff589f7',
      best_song:
        'https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/140006470&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true',
    },

    {
      name: 'Alesso',
      origin: 'Sweden',
      age: '26 years old',
      artist_id: '69fa09f6e181093fe0ea2ce1a4099066509f7837',
      best_song:
        'https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/288914798&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true',
    },
  ],
};
const minAge = 40;

const output = input.artists.filter(cur => minAge < parseInt(cur.age));
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1. you don't need [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), you can just use plain string.
2. Don't use `keyup`, use [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput) instead as event for such things: it also get things if the user paste the value using a different device than keyboard – e.g. mouse.
3. Don't use [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) since it returns a live HTMLCollection. Use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead, that returns a static NodeList. It also supports [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) directly, so you don't need to use `Array.from`.
4. Don't [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the variable, as `ageList` in the code you wrote, for example: it can lead to unexpected bugs.

Said that:

```
// you might not want to query all the time this list,
// every time the user change the input value.
const ageList = document.querySelectorAll('.artist-info');

document.querySelector('.search-age').addEventListener('input' , e => {
    // no need to lowercase, it's numeric.
    // you might want to add some check or constraint on
    // <input> validation
    const term = +e.target.value;

    ageList.forEach(node => {
      const artistAge = node.querySelector('.age').textContent;
      node.style.display = parseInt(artistAge, 10) >= term ? 'flex' : 'none';
    })
  });
```